# Let download function receive string parameter

Tags: vb.net, parameters

My codes are working. All I want is let `Download()` function receive string parameter without using `ResultBox.Text`

As of now I have this code and it produces result in `ResultBox.Text` and download it using `Download()` function.

```
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    If ReportType = 1 Then
        SmartSpendDbConnection.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand(SmartSpendDBReport, SmartSpendDbConnection)
        Dim reader As OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sector", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = Sector
        If IsNothing(Sector) Or Sector = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please complete")
        Else
            While reader.Read()
                For i = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
                    sb.Append(reader(i))
                    If i <> reader.FieldCount - 1 Then
                        sb.Append(",")
                    End If
                Next i
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)
            End While
            SmartSpendDbConnection.Close()
        End If
        ResultBox.Text = sb.ToString
        Download()
    Else
        MsgBox("No report is present!")
    End If
```

And this is my `Download()` function code.

```
Function Download() As String

    Dim strb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim output As String = ResultBox.Text
    strb.Append(output)
    strb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)

    Dim text As String = strb.ToString()

    Response.Clear()
    Response.ClearHeaders()

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", text.Length.ToString())
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=""output.csv""")

    Response.Write(text)
    Response.[End]()

    Return output

End Function
```

P.S. If you have clarification please comment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you're asking is fairly simple, and there are literally millions of examples (including documentation) out there! What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to change the `Download()` function to. `Function Download(ByVal s As String) As String`

Comment: @Visual Vincent can you give me an example regarding my problem? Thanks! :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Though you have already done half of what you asked: That snippet you just shared is valid syntax so it should work (if it doesn't, please tell me what's wrong and any error messages). Now you just gotta use the `s` parameter for what you need it for.

Comment: I already solved my problem well thanks I did what you said. @Visual Vincent